# Mean of a squared random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

if I have a random variable $x$ ~ $N(0,1)$, what is the expected value of $x^2$? Is there a general rule to calculate expected values of squared variables? Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, be aware that, if $X$ has PDF $f$ then $$E(X^2)=\int_\mathbb Rx^2f(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There is a connection between the variance of $x$ and the expected value of $x^{2}$. If you write both down separately you'll see it.

Comment: Ok I get it now :) Thanks!

Comment: @user322504 Great!

Answer (score -1):

If $X$ follows Standard Normal.then  $X^2$ follows Chi Square with 1 degrees of freedom..
And the Expected value of a  Chi Square is the degrees of freedom itself So $$E(X^2)=1$$
As far as a general rule, there is none you have to figure it out for yourself by practicing

Comment: Since the OP already expressed that he figured this out, I'll write it out here. Since $Var(X)=E(X^{2})-E(X)^{2}$ for **any** random variable $X$ regardless of the distribution, then there **is** a general rule, mainly $E(X^{2})=Var(X)+E(X)^{2}$. I.e. if $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$, then $E(X^{2})=\mu^{2}+\sigma^{2}$.

Comment: "As far as a general rule, there is none you have to figure it out for yourself by practicing" Please refer to my comment on main.